# Passing too many phone numbers to a url failed - Send SMS API

Tags: php, mysql, sms

I have an application that am building and implemented a sms API inside it, but it sends to few numbers, when I select all from database and send, it ought to send to about 1100 numbers, but it does nothing.

I figured out it wasn't sending because of the length of the url the numbers was passed into because I echoed the numbers and copied them into the textarea that does the sending earlier.

I also reduced the number to about a hundred and fifty, yet it didn't throw an error but did not send, how do I correct this.

See my sample code for the sending below

```
    $phone_group_total = $phone_numbers.", ".$send_it.", ".$selected_staffs;
     function httpRequest($fields, $sendpage){
     $curl = curl_init($sendpage);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     $result = curl_exec($curl);
     curl_close($curl);

    $sendpage ="http://smsexperience.com/components/com_spc/smsapi.php?";
    $sendsms ="username=user&password=pass";
    $sendsms .="&sender=$sender_id";
    $sendsms .="&recipient=".$phone_group_total; 
    $sendsms .="&message=$message";
    httpRequest($sendsms, $sendpage);
```

I used a get method for my form submission, I tried using post and my messages weren't sending. How do I fix it and send to large number set. Thanks.

Comment: The URL is limited to 2000 characters, which explains why you url is truncated. You will need to use `POST`.

To get help on why `POST` is not working, you'll have to show the code you were using.

Comment: function is not closed properly in sample code.

Comment: missed closing the function when posting the question, the code am using for post is as follows;

Answer (score 0):

```
   if(isset($_POST['send_sms']))
  {
  $sender_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sender_id']);
  $phone_numbers = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone_numbers']);   
  $message = ($_POST['message']);   
  $client_phone = ($_POST['client_phone']);
  $employee_phone = ($_POST['employee_phone']);
  $tailor_phone = ($_POST['tailor_phone']);

  if($client_phone!="")
  {
   $sql = "SELECT mobile_phone FROM personal_details";  
   $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
   $recipients = array();

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $recipients[] = $row['mobile_phone'];
   }

  $send_it = implode(', ', $recipients);

  }

   if($employee_phone!="")
 {
   $sql1 = "SELECT mobile_phone FROM employee_db";  
  $res1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
 $recipients1 = array();

  while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($res1)) {
  $recipients1[] = $row1['mobile_phone'];
  }

  $send_it1 = implode(', ', $recipients1);
  }

  if($tailor_phone!="")
  {
  $sql2 = "SELECT mobile_phone FROM employee_db WHERE department='Tailors'";  
   $res2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
   $recipients2 = array();

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2)) {
$recipients2[] = $row2['mobile_phone'];
 }

 $send_it2 = implode(', ', $recipients2);
 }

  if($tailor_phone !="" && $employee_phone!="")
 {$selected_staffs = $send_it1;}else if($tailor_phone=='tailors' &&      $employee_phone=="")
 {$selected_staffs = $send_it2;}else if($tailor_phone=="" &&     $employee_phone=='employees')
 {$selected_staffs = $send_it1;}

 if($_POST['phone_numbers']=="")
 {
$phone_group_total = $send_it.", ".$selected_staffs;
 }else{
 $phone_group_total =       $phone_numbers.", ".$send_it.", ".$selected_staffs;}     
 function httpRequest     ($fields, $sendpage){
$curl = curl_init($sendpage);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
 }

    $sendpage ="http://smsexperience.com/components/com_spc/smsapi.php?";
    $sendsms ="username=user&password=pass";
    $sendsms .="&sender=$sender_id";
    $sendsms .="&recipient=".$phone_group_total;         $sendsms .="&message=$message";
    httpRequest($sendsms, $sendpage); }
```

This is the post sample for my code, and it does not even see the variables send_it and so on. But the Get method sees everything and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was now able to solve the problem of passing too many arguments to a url by using a post method and changing the if(isset($_POST['send_sms'])) with if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") and that started submitting the form values correctly and also sends my sms. I also noticed that with a long set of number and a new line is used to separate the numbers, the mysql_real_escape_string converts the lines to characters and the numbers does not submit to the sms API, therefore the solution was to remove the command mysql_real_escape_string and the sms worked like magic for long sets of numbers.